# grep: return NULL if false

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I'm trying use grep to extract attributes from a large collection of XML files. I've tried using`grep -E -m 1 -o -Z "<tag>(.*)</tag>" /home/somepath/*.xml || printf "NULL"` but for some reason, it doesn't return NULL for a file if the regex doesn't match. The endgame here is to build a rudimentary SQL database of these files, using the information from the tags to populate columns. This is my first foray into DBs, so maybe I'm going about it all wrong?

Comment: Do you want a NULL per file that doesn't match? The `||` applies to the entire `grep` command, so the `printf` is only going to be executed if `grep` returns non-zero, which it will only do if *no* file matches.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being you want something per file, you'll have to use a `grep` per file, something like:

```
$ find /home/somepath -type f -name '*.xml' | \
> while read path; do \
> grep -E -H -m 1 -o -Z "<tag>(.*)</tag>" "$path" || echo -e "$path\x00NULL"; \
> done
```

Breaking it down:

```
$ find /home/somepath -type f -name '*.xml' -print | \
```

This generates the list of files to search and pipes them into the `while`. The only thing this needs to do is print one path per line, so there are lots of ways to do this.

```
> while read path;do \
```

This reads each line into the `path` shell variable and loops until `read` returns `false`, which it does when it reaches end-of-file, which it does when `find` has generated all the paths it's going to.

```
> grep -E -H -m 1 -o -Z "<tag>(.*)</tag>" "$path" || echo -e "$path\x00NULL"; \
```

This searches the current file (in `$path`). If the pattern isn't found in the file, `grep` returns `false` (i.e. exits with a non-zero exit code), so the `echo` is executed. The `-e` says to interpret escapes, so the `echo` will print the current path, an ASCII `nul`, and the literal `NULL`. That's to emulate `grep`'s output, which will be the current path (forced by `-H`, being `grep` wouldn't normally output the path when searching a single file), an ASCII `nul` (because of the `-Z`) and the matched text.

```
> done
```

Closes out the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, blm, that was the right script for the job. I also really appreciate your detailed explanation, first showing me what I was doing wrong and detailing why my script failed, then showing how to solve the problem, rather than just giving me answer.

Comment: @StuporUser Cool, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
grep -E -m 1 -o -Z "<tag>(.*)</tag>" /home/somepath/*.xml 2>&- || echo "NULL"
```

Comment: Pretty much the same result as before; removed a colon from each line of output, but no other change.

Comment: Which colon? Could you give some more  context?

Comment: '/home/somepath/B06614.xml:<author>William'        became                    '/home/somepath/B06614.xml<author>William'

Comment: The colon disappears because the `-Z` says to replace it with an ASCII `nul`.